# server 2003 r2 console login hangs with grey screen, server continues to work properly though

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop, remote, console

i have a server 2003 member server in a domain that hangs on local console login and under remote desktop connection (rdc).

i have disconnected sessions on that server from command line on another computer but still no luck.

i fear that the only logical solution might be the reset!. but i don't want to do that. any other advice? thanks.

as a last effort i will try to pull the apc battery out of the ac socket and hope that the server will shut down gracefully when the battery gets to 20% left.

thanks again.
gd

Comment: Is there anything amiss in the event logs? (I'm assuming since you say that it "continues to work properly" that you can remotely access the event logs.) Have you made any recent changes to the computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to soft-shutdown the server, and pressing the power button doesn't do that, you can use the "shutdown" console command to remotely shutdown the server (or shutdown -r to restart it). just type "shutdown /?" in cmd to see the syntax.

Assuming the problem recurs, and the hang is on the login phase, i had a similar problem on a couple of my servers that had to do with domain authentication. I don't remember specifics, but upgrading to SP2 and installing a specific hotfix for the problem fixed it. (i don't remember the KB number, but a search of the technet for "windows hangs on login" should provide clues)

Comment: yes that did it for anyone else looking for a comfirmation.gd

Answer (score 0):

That's interesting.

Does this help?

http://forums.techarena.in/small-business-server/844637.htm#post3288398